# How to get src in an image using class?

Tags: python, html, css, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Hi I am trying to get the src data from the image on the website, I locate the image using the class since it is unique. With the code below it is able to locate the image but is unable to save the image to mongodb and shows up as null, so want to find the src and save the link instead.

ps. the code works for other classes but not sure how to locate the src and save it into "findImage".

https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/6236298/vegetable

postal code is : 56000

```
cate_list = [
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/1208101/fresh-foods",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/8630656/ready-to-eat",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/6528959/grocery",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/6758871/snacks",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/8124135/chill-&-frozen",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/4995043/beverage",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/3405538/household",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/493239/baby-&-kids",
]


cookies = {
    "hideLocationOverlay": "true",
    "selectedShippingState": "Kuala Lumpur",
    "selectedPostalCode": "56000",
}

for x in range(len(cate_list)):

    url = cate_list[x]

    # convert soup to readable html
    result = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies)
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")

# a for loop located here to loop through all the products

                # <span class="n_MyDQk4X3P0XRRoTnOe a8H5VCTgYjZnRCen1YkC">myAEON2go Signature Taman Maluri</span>
                findImage = j.find("img", {"class": "pgJEkulRiYnxQNzO8njV shown"})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To extract the value of `src` attribute simply call `.get('src')` on your element.

Try to change your strategy selecting elements and avoid using classes that are often dynamically - I recommend to use more static identifier as well as HTML structure.

```
for url in cate_list:

    result = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies,headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
    for e in doc.select('.g-product-list li'):
        print(e.img.get('src'))
```

**Note:** *Iterating your `list` do not need `range(len())` construct*

##### Example

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

cate_list = [
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/1208101/fresh-foods",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/8630656/ready-to-eat",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/6528959/grocery",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/6758871/snacks",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/8124135/chill-&-frozen",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/4995043/beverage",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/3405538/household",
    "https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/493239/baby-&-kids",
]


cookies = {
    "hideLocationOverlay": "true",
    "selectedShippingState": "Kuala Lumpur",
    "selectedPostalCode": "56000",
}

for url in cate_list:

    result = requests.get(url, cookies=cookies,headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    doc = BeautifulSoup(result.text, "html.parser")
    for e in doc.select('.g-product-list li'):
        print(e.img.get('src').split(')/')[-1])
```

##### Output

```
https://assets.myboxed.com.my/1659400060229.jpg
https://assets.myboxed.com.my/1662502067580.jpg
https://assets.myboxed.com.my/1658448744726.jpg
https://assets.myboxed.com.my/1627880003755.jpg
https://assets.myboxed.com.my/1662507451284.jpg
https://assets.myboxed.com.my/1662501936757.jpg
https://assets.myboxed.com.my/1659400602324.jpg
https://assets.myboxed.com.my/1627880346297.jpg
https://assets.myboxed.com.my/1662501743853.jpg
...
```

Comment: I used the code to replace since a for loop already exist and it works, thanks for the help. Now that I got it is there a way to update the link because the website compress the link image. For example the link : //images.myboxed.com.my/unsafe/trim/fit-in/256x200/filters:quality(10):max_bytes(5000):fill(white)/https://assets.myboxed.com.my/1659400060229.jpg . I tested that if i change the resolution and change quality to 100 it works.

Comment: Simply split the string `e.img.get('src').split(')/')[-1]` or extract url - Updated example.

Comment: Oh I understand the code now, thanks. I was questioning the removal of additional data of the url.

Answer (score 1):

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
from urllib.parse import urljoin
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor, as_completed

cookies = {
    "hideLocationOverlay": "true",
    "selectedShippingState": "Kuala Lumpur",
    "selectedPostalCode": "56000",
}

links = [
    "8630656/ready-to-eat",
    "1208101/fresh-foods",
    "6528959/grocery",
    "6758871/snacks",
    "8124135/chill-&-frozen",
    "4995043/beverage",
    "3405538/household",
    "493239/baby-&-kids",
]
allin = []


def get_soup(content):
    return BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml', parse_only=SoupStrainer('img', class_="pgJEkulRiYnxQNzO8njV"))


def worker(req, url, link):
    r = req.get(url + link)
    soup = get_soup(r.content)
    return [urljoin(url, x['src']) for x in soup.select('img')]


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req, ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=10) as executor:
        req.cookies.update(cookies)
        fs = (executor.submit(worker, req, url, link) for link in links)
        for f in as_completed(fs):
            allin.extend(f.result())
        print(allin)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main('https://myaeon2go.com/products/category/')
```